# How to mark Username with rest-auth in the DRF as a name instead of a number

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer, django-rest-auth

I am going to use Django to receive the value of Arduino and serialize it into REST API. First of all, member management function was established with rest-auth and 'name' variable was designated as a foreign key to store sensor values for each user by creating an aduinos model. After running the server and logging in, I checked the API that contains the data of each user, and there was a number next to the name, not the user's username. I wonder how to change this to username instead of number. here is my code

models.py

```
class arduino (models.Model) :
    name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    temp = models.FloatField()
    humi = models.FloatField()
```

serializers.py

```
class arduinoSerializers (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    class Meta :
        model = arduino
        fields = ('name', 'temp', 'humi')
```

views.py

```
class arduinoViewSet (viewsets.ViewSet) :
    def dataSend (self, request) :
        queryset = arduino.objects.all()
        serializer = arduinoSerializers(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look of the serializer field argument **[`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)**

```
class arduinoSerializers (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='name.username')

    class Meta :
        model = arduino
        fields = ('name', 'temp', 'humi')
```

Comment: @leedjango welcome to SO, just FYI, if you are pleased with the answer, you can accept  it https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?noredirect=1&lq=1